Reference for formula of character of the homology of a complex of representations
I don't know much about representation theory or K theory but want to cite something like the following statement. Does someone have a reference for this?
Let $A \overset{\alpha}{\to} B \overset{\beta}{\to} C$ be a chain complex of representations of a (compact) group $G$. Then the cohomology $H := \frac{\ker \beta}{\mathrm{im\ } \alpha}$ is a representation of $G$ too, and its character is the alternating sum of the characters of the chain representations:
$$ \chi_H(g) = -\chi_A(g) + \chi_B(g) - \chi_C(g) $$
I would very much appreciate any recommendations.

This is false. The character of the homology depends on the boundary maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$, e.g. if $\alpha = \beta = 0$ then $H \cong B$ but if, for example, $B = C$ and $\beta = \text{id}_B$ then $H = 0$.
What is true is that if $V_{\bullet}$ is a finite chain complex of f.d. representations of a group $G$, not necessarily compact, with homology $H_{\bullet}$, then we have an equality of "Euler characteristic" characters
$$\sum_i (-1)^i \chi_{H_i}(g) = \sum_i (-1)^i \chi_{V_i}(g).$$
This is a special case of the same identity for the trace of a chain map $V_{\bullet} \to V_{\bullet}$. It does not specialize to the statement you want because your chain complex has three homology groups and you're only looking at one of them; the other two are $\ker(\alpha)$ and $C/\text{im}(\beta)$.

You're right, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are injective and surjective in my case. Do I not need that the category of representations in question is semisimple, such that for a quotient representation $Q = R/I$ the character is $\chi_Q = \chi_R - \chi_I$? Could you maybe elaborate what you mean by trace of a chain map?

@notmyrealname: no, you don't need semisimplicity, this is just a fact about traces. Namely, if $R$ is a f.d. vector space and $I$ a subspace of it, and $T : R \to R$ is a linear map preserving $I$, then $T$ acts on the short exact sequence $0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$, and the trace is additive. By the trace of a chain map $T$ I mean either of the "Euler characteristic" alternating sums above, but with $\chi_{H_i}(g)$ replaced by the trace of $H_i(T)$ and so forth.
